# Setting value of specific xmlNode

Tags: c#, .net, xml

currently I am working on a c# windows forms application, but I have the following problem:

I have the listed below xml:

```
  <new>
    <Company></Company>
    <DateTime></DateTime>
    <Message></Message>
    <Status><Status>
  </new>
  <new>
    <Company></Company>
    <DateTime></DateTime>
    <Message></Message>
    <Status><Status>
  </new>
  <new>
    <Company></Company>
    <DateTime></DateTime>
    <Message></Message>
    <Status><Status>
  </new>
  <new>
    <Company></Company>
    <DateTime></DateTime>
    <Message></Message>
    <Status><Status>
  </new>
  <new>
    <Company></Company>
    <DateTime></DateTime>
    <Message></Message>
    <Status><Status>
  </new>
```

I am getting the data like this:

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Globals.pathNotifFile);
    var notifDateTime = doc.Descendants("DateTime");
    var message = doc.Descendants("Message");
    var company = doc.Descendants("Company");
    var sendStatus = doc.Descendants("Status");

    var dateTimeCollection = new List<String>();
    var messageCollection = new List<String>();
    var companyCollection = new List<String>();
    var statusCollection = new List<String>();

    foreach (var dateTimeOfNotification in notifDateTime)
    {
        dateTimeCollection.Add(dateTimeOfNotification.Value);
    }

    foreach (var messages in message)
    {
        messageCollection.Add(messages.Value);
    }

    foreach (var companys in company)
    {
        companyCollection.Add(companys.Value);
    }

    foreach (var isSent in sendStatus)
    {
        statusCollection.Add(isSent.Value);
    }

    return Tuple.Create(dateTimeCollection, messageCollection, companyCollection, statusCollection);
```

And I am doing this with the data of the xml file

```
        Tuple<List<String>, List<String>, List<String>, List<String>> t = GetDataFromFile();
        List<String> dateTimeCollection = t.Item1;
        List<String> messageCollection = t.Item2;
        List<String> companyCollection = t.Item3;
        List<String> statusCollection = t.Item4;

        foreach (var notifDateTime in dateTimeCollection)
        {
            int index = dateTimeCollection.IndexOf(notifDateTime);
            if (Int32.Parse(statusCollection[index]) == 1 || statusCollection[index] == string.Empty)
            {
                if (notifDateTime != string.Empty)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToDateTime(notifDateTime) == DateTime.Now)
                    {
                        SendMessageToUser(messageCollection[index], companyCollection[index]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

After that in SendMessageToUser I am sending the message and I get a response 1,2 or 3, but my problem is about getting the exact node where I must write the status. The function I use to write the status is:

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(Globals.pathNotifFile);

    XmlNode commentsElement = doc.SelectSingleNode("Status");
    commentsElement.InnerText = status.ToString();

    doc.Save(Globals.pathNotifFile);
```

So in the **doc.SelectSingleNode(("Status"))** I must put the selected node and update it. Any ideas how I can do that

Comment: Any particular reason, why you are not deserializing your XML to object, do all the logic on the object, serialize the object to XML? That would make what you are trying to achieve soooo much easier

Comment: I don't know how, sorry. I'm still learning and this is the way I know about handling xml data. Can you show me how?

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how serialization/deserialization looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer directly your question without any code modification - 
If you want to select specific node in your case using xpath, you can also do it like that:

```
doc.SelectSingleNode("//new[1]/Status");
```

Of course instead of "1" you can put whatever index you want (they are not zero-based)

EDIT: As you stated in your comment that you did not take into consideration serialization/deserialization, I strongly encourage you to try using it. To get you going define your data as following:

```
[Serializable]
public class root
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("new")]
    public Node[] @new { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Node
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    //other properties
}
```

And now you can do:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var data = Deserialize();
    //do your logic on normal object
    Serialize(data);


}

static root Deserialize()
{
    using (var file = File.Open("test.txt", FileMode.Open))
    {
        XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
        xRoot.ElementName = "root";
        xRoot.IsNullable = true;
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(root), xRoot);
        return (root)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(file);
    }
}

static void Serialize(root data)
{
    using (var file = File.Create("result.txt"))
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(root));
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(file, data);
    }
}
```

Just an example, of course this is a huge topic and you can find plenty of examples on SO and other sites

Answer (score 1):

I would parse like code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication49
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants("new").Select(x => new {
                company = (string)x.Element("Company"),
                dateTime = (DateTime)x.Element("DateTime"),
                message = (string)x.Element("Message"),
                status = (string)x.Element("Status")
            }).ToList();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, You should change the way you are parsing the file to something like this:

```
var newsDatas = xdoc.Descendants("new")
                .Select(
                    element =>
                        new 
                        {
                            Company = element.Element("Company").Value,
                            DateTime = element.Element("DateTime").Value,
                            Message = element.Element("Message").Value,
                            Node = element
                        });
```

Then loop through the parsed tree and update the `Status` in the relevant `Node`

```
foreach (var newsData in newsDatas) 
{
    // .. You logic
    SendMessageToUser(newsData.Message, newsData.Company);

    string status = ....;
    newsData.Node.Element("Status").Value = status;
}
```

And last, save the XDocument:

```
doc.Save(Globals.pathNotifFile);
```